# Addon to the FormCraft plugin doesn't work (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, formcraft

I'm trying to create an addon for the FormCraft Wordpress plugin and I'm having some trouble with it.
I've edited a demo addon based on the FormCraft documentation, added it to my Wordpress as a plugin. But it doesn't seem to work.

I tried just copy-pasting the demo addon from http://formcraft-wp.com/help/developing-an-add-on-for-formcraft/. But it also didn't work.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

    /*
    Plugin Name: FormCraft Demo Add-On
    Plugin URI: http://ncrafts.net/
    Description: Demo Add-on for FormCraft
    Author: nCrafts
    Author URI: http://ncrafts.net
    Version: 1
    Text Domain: formcraft-demo
    */

    // Tell FormCraft our add-on exists
    add_action('formcraft_addon_init', 'formcraft_demo_addon');
    function formcraft_demo_addon()
    {
        register_formcraft_addon( 'demo_addon_settings', 0, 'Demo Addon', 'DemoController');
    }

    // We show a simple text field in the add-on's settings
    function demo_addon_settings() {
        echo "<input style='margin: 20px 10%; width: 80%' placeholder='Banned hosts' type='text' ng-model='Addons.DemoAddon.banned_hosts'>";
    }

    add_action('formcraft_after_save', 'your_function', 10, 4);
    function your_function($content, $meta, $raw_content, $integrations)
    {
        file_get_contents('https://my-app.com/send_request?formcraft=true');
    }
?>
```

Nothing is showing up in the settings and based on my server logs nothing is being sent in the formcraft_after_save action.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

author of FormCraft here.

Firstly, please make sure you are using FormCraft version 3.2.6 or above. Is the Demo Addon showing up when you edit any form, and go to Add-Ons -> Installed?

You can reach me directly at nish at ncrafts dot net as well.